# Is "locking" requirements in conda's meta.yaml a good idea?

Tags: python, conda

In a recent conversation with a colleague we were discussing whether it is a best practice to "lock" or specify a certain major version in the meta.yaml file like so:

```
requirements:
  build:
    - python 3.5.*
    - pyserial 2.7.*
  run:
    - python 3.5.*
    - pyserial 2.7.*
```

instead of ...

```
requirements:
  build:
    - python >=3.5
    - pyserial >=2.7
  run:
    - python >=3.5
    - pyserial >=2.7
```

His concern, which I understand, is that the developers of pyserial, as an example, might change something significantly in, say, version 3.0 that will break our modules. Is this concern justifiable to locking down fairly specific version of the dependencies?

I argue that while dependencies *could* very well break our code, that the people that write those dependencies are taking a lot of that into account and that if something should break it would be trivial to downgrade to a working version anyway. And I've not seen such a restrictive model as the one he is suggesting. Is there a reason for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this:

```
requirements:
  build:
    - python 3.5.*
    - pyserial 2.7.*
  run:
    - python 3.5.*
    - pyserial 2.7.*
```

you are not locking on a major version, but on a minor version, locking on a major version would require:

```
requirements:
  build:
    - python 3.*.*
    - pyserial 2.*.*
  run:
    - python 3.*.*
    - pyserial 2.*.*
```

(or maybe just one `*` instead of `*.*`).

This kind of locking is equivalent to using `>=` and `<` when installing with `pip` on minor version number:

```
pip install 'some.package>=0.14.0,<0.15'
```

or on major version number:

```
pip install 'some.package>=0.0,<1.0'
```

There are multiple aspects to consider when locking:

### The semantics

Preferably there are predefined semantics on what it means to change the major, minor and micro/build/revision number of package. If changing the major version number of a package is defined as an API change that may break something, then *not* fixing (i.e using just `>=`) will break something.

These semantics are not the same for each package. Especially if the major version is 0, a package might still change and you might want to fix on the minor version number (e.g. using 0.3.*, or in pip: `>=0.3,<0.4`)

### The complexity of your dependencies

If you have multiple dependencies, and the dependencies are dependent on each other, you might have non-overlapping locking requirements. E.g. you specify `pyserial 2.7.*` and `some.package 0.4.*` and then `some.package` requires `pyserial 2.5.*`

### How soon will you find out breakage, and how easy is it to fix it

If you have proper test coverage you should be able to find out if a new version of some package breaks your "build". It then depends on how easy it is to correct that (e.g. find the last working version of such package)  and whether that can be done in time. If you have an urgent bug fix in your own software, and deployment is delayed because you didn't lock and now have to spend time finding the culprit package and locking it down, this might be unacceptable.

### What do you lose if you don't have the latest version

You probably want all the bug fixes and non of the incompatibilities when selecting another package. On the other hand you should already have found all of the bugs that might exists in all of the packages that you depend upon, if you have proper test coverage, which is an argument for "tight" locking on specific versions.

### Chances of breakage within the selected lock range

If a package, that you depend upon, has no—or little—test coverage itself, and/or has a reputation for breaking even on micro/build version number changes, you might want to lock it down completely.

---

What is actually best, as so often, depends on all of the above. If you cannot deal with delays in deployment—figuring out on which minor version a package went wrong—you have to lock down. But if your package dependency tree is complex, you might have to loosen restrictions in order to be able to install all packages.

Most important in all of this is knowing what the consequences are what you are doing. Tight locking on complex projects might take considerable time for you to find "allowed" version number ranges for package, just make sure you have that time when you are forced having to change it.

So yes there might be a reason for the tight locking your colleague suggests. But whether that is warranted in your situation depends on all the factors mentioned above.